# Battery3 is playing monophonic for unknown reason

Tags: music, production

I have a simple quarter note bass drum and a snare on the backbeat (2 and 4). For some stupid reason, Battery decided to cut out the bass drum on the snare hits. Is there any reason for this? I've used Battery for at least 4 years now and it's never done that before.

Comment: Do you perhaps have the number of voices set to 1, or the bass and snare in the same choke group?